# Destroy a post after 30 days from its creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

For learning purposes I created a blog, now I want to destroy a post automatically after 30 days from its creation. how can I do it?

This is my Posts controller

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end
  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to posts_path
  end
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
     redirect_to posts_path
  end
```

Comment: You have great and helpful answers here. I think the author deserve a vote up    and ✅  to accept this his/her because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution.

Answer (score 6):

I would set up a task with [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) that runs every 1 day.

To generate a task:

```
rails g task posts delete_30_days_old
```

Then on the created file (lib/tasks/posts.rb), add the following code:

```
namespace :posts do
  desc "TODO"
  task delete_30_days_old: :environment do
    Post.where(['created_at < ?', 30.days.ago]).destroy_all
  end
end
```

This is of course if you want to delete the posts that have more than 30 days, other answers might as well work but I would rather have my database with clean data that I'll use on my application.

Answer (score 3):

Posts will be stored in your database.  The model is what interacts with your database.  Your controller never sees the database, it only sees what the model shows it.  If you wanted to pull from the database using your model inside the controller you could do it with this code.

`@posts = Post.where('created_at >= :thirty_days_ago', thiryty_days_ago: Time.now - 30.days)`

`Post` in this code calls you app/model/Post.rb which inherited active record.  `.where` is the active record method that looks at your database based on the stuff you define.  Here we have defined to pull only rows where the `created_at` column has a time in it that is 30 days ago.

If you look inside your database you'll notice the created_at column was automagically put in there for you.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution also and went to see if anyone else supplied it. I would go with this approach having similar requirement

Comment: But whith this approach i can still have access to the posts via their URL

Comment: @user3304070 - if you delete the posts, they are no longer accessible via their URL because they have been removed from the database.

Comment: @user3304070, You will NOT be able to access posts in your database with a url.  A url gets routed via your config/routes.rb which tells it which controller to hit.  Inside the controller you call on your model and the model pulls from the database.  Unless you have a url that hits a different controller that pulls from that database WITHOUT specifying you ONLY want posts that are 30 days or younger.  Only then will you have access to those posts.

Comment: @toolz 
I have tested your solution. It will only SHOW on index view any record created less than 30 days. And for example: I have a post older than 30 days such as `/posts/22`, I can access it's URL via show view. Nothing gets deleted.  
@maximgladkov show a sultion where I can access that URL via show view.
Your solution is neat and so readable which I like. You show the beauty of Ruby. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Along with the aforementioned `whenever` gem, you can also use two gems called [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org) and [Sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq) for scheduling tasks/workers.

I've been using these on a large app at work and am very pleased with it. It's fast (uses Redis, added with a simple gem, reliable, and easy to use).

```
# in app/workers/clean_posts.rb
class CleanPosts
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidetiq::Schedulable

  recurrence { monthly }

  def perform
    # stealing from toolz
    Post.where('created_at >= :thirty_days_ago', thiryty_days_ago: Time.now - 30.days).destroy_all
  end
end
```

This will, however, remove the posts from your DB and they will no longer be accessible by your application.

Comment: FWIW the where query can be simplified to `Post.where('created_at >= ?', 30.days.ago)`.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve desired result, you need to change your `index` action like this:

```
def index
    @posts = Post.where(created_at: 30.days.ago..Time.now)
end
```

In such way, you won't need to destroy posts and you will get the desired result.

If you need to limit access to the older posts, then you can use:

```
def show
    @post = Post.where(created_at: 30.days.ago..Time.now).find(params[:id])
end
```

And, if we are speaking about code beauty, then you should move `where(created_at: 30.days.ago..Time.now)` part to a scope in your model, like this:

```
class Post
   ...

   scope :recent, -> { where(created_at: 30.days.ago..Time.now) }
end
```

And use it like this:

```
Post.recent #=> to get list of recent posts
Post.recent.find(params[:id]) #=> to get recent post with specified id
```

Comment: this solution work but I can still have access to the posts via URL

Comment: @userails I think the show method takes care of hiding the record. I have tested it with a recored older than 30 days and I got can't find record error `Couldn't find Post with 'id'=20 [WHERE ("posts"."created_at" BETWEEN $1 AND $2)]` which is caused by show method. This still doesn't delete or destroy any recored.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that from your controller, you need to add some functionality to your application.

You will need a cron job running everyday that will look for posts that are more than 30 days old and destroy them.

eg `Post.where('created_at < ?', 30.days.ago)`

For handling the cron jobs better you might consider using the [whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) that helps a lot and keeps the cron setup in your app.